# Getting List / Deleting the Unused Option values using API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.3.4, dropdown-options, attribute-value

Need to get all the unused attribute value and delete it via API. How to get the Unused attribute list using SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query in the Database

```
SELECT
  eao.attribute_id,
  ea.attribute_code,
  eaov.value_id,
  eaov.value
FROM eav_attribute_option AS eao
  INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON eao.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS eaov ON eaov.option_id = eao.option_id
WHERE eao.option_id NOT IN (
  SELECT value
  FROM catalog_product_entity_int
  WHERE attribute_id = eao.attribute_id
) AND  ea.attribute_code = 'your_attribute_code';
```

It will lists options of **your_attribute_code** is not used by any product

Review the list option before deleting them

**API**

You can check the **DELETE API** in Swagger **catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1**

```
API URL: YourDoamin/rest/all/V1/products/attributes/**attribute_code**/options/**option_id**
```